# CellForRowAtIndexPath in a nib project

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nib

I have implemented the CellForRowAtIndexPath method in my project that works.

It looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"StackTableViewCell";

    Target *target = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    StackTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StackTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.cellLabel.text = target.body;

    cell.cellLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Candara-Bold" size:20];[UIFont fontWithName:@"Candara-Bold" size:20];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

but there is something that bothers me and it's that I don't really understand what happened in this part (I took it from some tutorial):

```
if (!cell)
        {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StackTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
```

can someone please help me understand this?

thanks!

Comment: Have you read through the relevant section of the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS"?

Comment: what section should i read?

Comment: Try https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10 and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1

Comment: Also read the docs for `UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

Answer (score 2):

If the table view doesn't have a cell available to re-use, load the objects that exist in StackTableViewCell.xib.  Assume that the first one you find that's defined at the top level can be instantiated as the type of cell that you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!cell)
        {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StackTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
```

You are trying to load cell from nib when cell is nil.

Usually, I do like this:

in ViewDidLoad

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"StackTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

so in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method you can get cell and you will not need to check if it nil or not, because it will always return cell

```
StackTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```